# Get input text value inside td with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a table by using CGridView, inside the table contain input text field which allow user to insert value. The issue is I can get the text from the table where there is no input field, but not with the one that contain input field.

Php:

```
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView',array(
    'id' => 'oc-list-upgradeRule',
    'dataProvider' => $upgradeRuleDataProvider,
    'selectableRows' => 2,
    'summaryText' => '',
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'header' => '',
            'id' => 'chkbox',
            'name' => 'checkBox',
            'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
        ),
        array(
            'header' => 'Min. Spending Amount',
            'id' => 'minSpendingAmount',
            'name' => 'minSpendingAmount',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHTML::textField("",$data["minSpendingAmount"],array())',
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
                      'style'=>'text-align: center;'
            )
         )
    )
));
?>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function () {
    var upgradeRenewDowngrade = $('.oc-upgrade-renew-downgrade');

    upgradeRenewDowngrade.find('.oc-save-upgrade-downgrade-rules').click(function (e) {
        var sel = $.fn.yiiGridView.getChecked('oc-list-upgradeRule', 'chkbox');
        var row = $.fn.yiiGridView.getRow('oc-list-upgradeRule', sel);
        var minSpendAmount = row.get(5);
        var input = $(minSpendAmount).html();

        //console.log($(input).val());
        console.log(minSpendAmount);
    })
})
```

From the code above, I only able to get td together with input text field.

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
    <input type="text" value="365" name id>
</td>
```

How to get the input text value? You may suggest other way to get the value from CGridView. Thanks.

Comment: Is minSpendAmount a text result, or can you browse it like an array in your console ?

Comment: @TakitIsy The minSpendAmount only show the <td> and <input> in console, neither text or array. With row, it show the whole <tr> jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so…
Playing a little with your code, I ended up with this:

```js
// Here, I only set my variable to be the same as yours
var minSpendAmount = '<td style="text-align: center;">    <input type="text" value="365" name id></td>';

// Code you may do instead of your current console.log(minSpendAmount)
var input = $(minSpendAmount).html();
console.log($(input).val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Tell me if that helps you, or not.

Comment: After using for a few days, there is a new issue which was it only gets the preset value, after i edit the value in input text field, it still only get the preset value? Any solution?

Comment: @Hoodini I don't get what you mean. Can you show me your new code?

Comment: My code is same as the one you suggest, it get the value where I preset in array, however, when i edit the input text field value, it still get the value that i preset in array

Comment: Ok, I get it. The problem is that your code is running on `$(document).ready()`, so it takes the value when the page is loaded the first time. You need to use a `.on("change"), function(){}` on your input element or `onclick`, or whatever.

Comment: Hi, I've edit my javascript on the question, but it still get the preset value even though I edit the value in the input text field.